# Javascript timer to close

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that closes an iframe footer pop-up I have.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="parent.adpHide('footer')" class='close'>
<img alt='' src="images/close.png" /></a>
```

That works fine, what I'm wanting though is to set a timer that after 5 seconds closes footer.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() { parent.adpHide('footer') }, 5000)
```

Comment: dang, I had everything but the function() and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Change your `onclick` to:

```
setTimeout( function() { parent.adpHide('footer'); }, 5000 );
```